# Custom image in a button in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a button which will do some action when pressed, suppose it calls a function _pressedButton() also if the user taps on it (or taps and hold), the image changes.

Consider this like a button with a custom picture on pressed.

In the follow-up, can I also change the image based on some external factor?
eg. if some function A returns true, show image 1, else show image 2

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how  to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I guess you could use a GestureDetector and have an image as a child (make it a variable). Now, you can change it like any other variable (in theory, haven't actually tried it out myself with images)

Comment: You can change the image based on a factor, have a look at this code https://github.com/AlexiCoard/flutter_firebase_auth_samples/blob/master/lib/myApp.dart#L34 It shows an example of context difference, You can also use setState() method to change the widget while not in the build method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can learn all about buttons and state in the [Flutter interactivity tutorial](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/).

For example, here is a button that shows a different cat every time each time it is clicked.

[image: cat button]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _url = getNewCatUrl();

  static String getNewCatUrl() {
    return 'http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg&size=small'
           '#${new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Cat Button'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _url = getNewCatUrl();
            });
          },
          child: new ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(),
            child: new Image.network(_url, fit: BoxFit.cover, gaplessPlayback: true),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So this was achieved using the `FloatingActionButton` widget which is inherently round. Isn't there a way to make an `IconButton` round?

Answer (score 0):

A handy way to achieve what you want is by using `GestureDetector()`

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          //desired action command
        },
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/icons/user.png'),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Result:

[image: Result]

*GestureDetector()* basically mimics a button.