# Flutter - onPressed function

Tags: flutter

I need to insert onpressed()function (navigator push to other page) on the icons bellow:

```
Column buildButtonColumn(IconData icon, String label) {
    Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
      return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
      Icon(icon, color: color),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        child: Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: color,
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     );
   }

   Widget buttonSection = Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        buildButtonColumn(Icons.call, 'CALL'),
        buildButtonColumn(Icons.near_me, 'ROUTE'),
        buildButtonColumn(Icons.share, 'SHARE'),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: sorry for the format error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497289/custom-image-in-a-button-in-flutter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of an `IconButton` widget for this.

```
IconButton(
     icon:  Icon(Icons.info),
     onPressed: (){
           // Do something               
     },
 )
```

of you can make use of `GestureDetector`

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    //Do something
  },
  child: icon: Icon(Icons.info),
)
```

**EDIT:**

With a little modification to the codes pasted below. Change buildButtonColumn tho this:

```
buildButtonColumn(icon, label, onTap) {
      Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(icon, color: color),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: color,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

and For button Section, use this.

```
Widget buttonSection = Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          buildButtonColumn(Icons.call, 'CALL', (){
                print('call');
          }),
          buildButtonColumn(Icons.near_me, 'ROUTE', (){
            print('route');
          }),
          buildButtonColumn(Icons.share, 'SHARE', (){
            print('share');
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: nonybrighto tks for replying but it is not working on my code. I need to use the Widget buttonSection with a container on the other hand i need to insert the function on the code. Is there possible?

Comment: how did you implement it? Show the code for buildButtonColumn

Comment: nonybrighto tks again, see above entire button code.

Comment: nonybrighto works very nice but how can I send the user to another page on each of 3 buttons? I tried using the onPressed but didn work I edited your change

Comment: just add `Navigator.pushNamed(context, label);` to each onPressed method or create a function for it.

Comment: what does the empty `()` do ?  I am reading through a Flutter book and it had an intro on Dart but don't understand for example `onPressed: () {},`

Comment: @mLstudent33 having an empty onPressed makes the button active/enabled so you can still get the splash effect and all even though the button has no action.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Column with GestureDetector:

To go to other Page you can use Navigator.pushNamed or Navigator.push, E.g with PushNamed is in Code

```
Widget buildButtonColumn(IconData icon, String label) {
    Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, label);
      },
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(icon, color: color),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
GestureDetector buildButtonColumn(IconData icon, String label){
    onTap(){
      print("Pressed");
    }
    Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Icon(icon, color: color),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            buildButtonColumn(Icons.call, 'CALL'),
            buildButtonColumn(Icons.near_me, 'ROUTE'),
            buildButtonColumn(Icons.share, 'SHARE'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```