# Create a button with an image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout

How do you create a button with an image using Flutter? It seems like the simplest thing to do, but the image does not fill the parent widget completely. This is what I have:

```
Container(child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
    child: FlatButton(onPressed: null,
        child: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'))))
```

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497289/custom-image-in-a-button-in-flutter) as guidance. My image looks like this:

[image]

Notice the padding around the PNG image - it's not in the code. Where does it come from? The PNG itself does not have canvas padding, so this must not be the correct technique.

All I need is a button with an image that fills the entire `FlatButton`, or another widget I can add actions to, without distorting the image.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having an image inside a `FlatButton` might not fit your requirements, as it takes care of some styling ( like that padding ) on its own.

To have full control on your button aspect you might want to build a custom widget ( even a simple `Container` with a custom `BoxDecoration` to display the image ) and wrap it with a gesture recognizer to handle user interactions ( a simple tap, in your case ). The simplest implementation would use a `GestureDetector`, but there are also other widgets, like `InkWell` that renders a material design ripple over the tappable widget surface on tap.

Comment: This worked. I ended up doing the following: 

`Expanded(
    child: Container(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: Ink.image(
          image: AssetImage(
              'path/the_image.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),`

Comment: I recommend using an `IconButton`, see some answers below.

Answer (score 91):

```
IconButton(
  icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'),
  iconSize: 50,
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

Comment: To remove the outline, padding should be set to `EdgeInsets.all(0.0).`

Comment: padding: EdgeInsets.zero

Answer (score 38):

I think this should work as well.
Just specify the padding for the FlatButton to zero.

```
Container(child: ConstrainedBox(
constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
child: FlatButton(
         onPressed: null,
         padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
         child: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'))))
```

Comment: Pretty much right, just note it should be `EdgeInsets.all(0.0)`.

Comment: `FlatButton` is now deprecated. Use `IconButton` instead.

Comment: It seems `IconButton` is also deprecated as well according to https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/issues/14668

Answer (score 20):

My opinion, the easier way and also most versatile is to use GestureDetector as it allows you to call different functions for different gestures like one tap, double-tap, long tap and so on.

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => _yourFunction('yourParameter'),
                child: Image.asset('yourimagefolder/yourimage.png'),
              ),
```

Answer (score 17):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {}, // Handle your callback.
  splashColor: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.5),
  child: Ink(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('your_image_asset'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Display image icon button with ripple effect over the image when pressed:

```
          Material(
            // needed
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => myOnTap, // needed
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/resize.png",
                width: 22,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: According to the Material guidelines, this is what is recommended... _The need for a ripple touch on any Widget._ How ever the IconButton works duly too! ;-)

Comment: I can't get this version to show a ripple effect.  (I get a better ripple effect using a FlatButton, but the ripple is only around the frame of the button, not over the image.)

Answer (score 7):

**Can use TextButton for this.**

```
 TextButton.icon(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'),
                  label: Text(
                    'Button Text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 6):

```dart
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {print('click on edit');},
    child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/icons/edit-button.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: 20,
    )
),
```

Comment: Please try to explain the code block rather giving it directly, explanation may help the community

Comment: Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58417172/6618622).

Answer (score 3):

Place your image in a `gestureDetector` like this:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Image.asset('path/the_image.png')
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is another answer with gestureDetector so, which one are the benefits of your reply?

Answer (score 1):

I'm create own inkwell have triple anim that take child and callback onPress **for non transparent background like image**

```
class InkWellApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  final Widget child;
  final EdgeInsets margin;

  final BorderRadius borderRadius;

  const InkWellApp(
      {Key key,
      this.onTap,
      this.child,
      this.borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero,
      this.margin = EdgeInsets.zero})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: margin,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          child,
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              borderRadius: borderRadius,
              child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: borderRadius,
                onTap: onTap,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then you can use it inside app with any widget or image like this

```
 InkWellApp(
        onTap: (){
                //your code here
           },
        child: yourWidget,
  ),
```

> Note : borderRadius and margin is optional parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                color: Colors.orange,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column( 
                  children: <Widget>[
                   Image.asset(name),
                    Text("Add")
                  ],
                );
```

you can add icons and images

Comment: `FlatButton` is now deprecated. Use `IconButton` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using Stack

```
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.6,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.2,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child:imageLoader1(img),
             /* Image.asset(
                "$img",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),*/
            ),
          ),

          Positioned(
            right: -10.0,
            bottom: 3.0,
            child: RawMaterialButton(
              onPressed: (){},
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Icon(
                  isFav
                      ?Icons.favorite
                      :Icons.favorite_border,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: 17,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],


      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Image button with Ripple Effect and Text on the bottom**

(of course you can remove the text part and Stack)

```
  Material(
    elevation: 4.0,
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    color: Colors.transparent,
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: [
        Ink.image(
          image: AssetImage(imagePath),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 120,
          height: 120,
          child: InkWell(onTap: () {}),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(label, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rounded rectangle button then follow the below code

```
TextButton(
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                          minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 200),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => null,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 500,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              **Positioned(
                                top: 0,
                                left: 0,
                                right: 0,**
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
                                    top: Radius.circular(20),
                                  ),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/miniMartGrocery.png',
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                  top: 10,
                                  left: screenSize.width * 0.84,
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 40,
                                    height: 40,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(100),
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                    child: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        FontAwesomeIcons.flag,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () => null,
                                    ),
                                  ))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```